# How do I keep a file open for reading

Tags: java

I want to be able to open a (very large) file and read data from arbitrary points at any time later,  without keeping the whole thing in memory.

Is this possible?

I want to open a handle to a file, nothing else will be reading/writing to this file, and be able to grab data from any given offset & length at a point later, without searching the disk for the file again.

I had assumed there would be some sort of

```
1, open handle to file
2, create reader
3, skip reader to X
4, read for Y
5, reset reader to 0
6, return to step 3
```

At first it seemed like `BufferedReader.mark` would be what I'm after, but the docs suggest that if I `mark, skip, read, reset` the contents from where I marked, to where I skipped, would be kept in memory?

From the docs,

> Limit on the number of characters that may be read while still
>   preserving the mark. An attempt to reset the stream after reading
>   characters up to this limit or beyond may fail. A limit value larger
>   than the size of the input buffer will cause a new buffer to be
>   allocated whose size is no smaller than limit. Therefore large values
>   should be used with care.

It says "read", so perhaps if I skip, it doesn't count towards this limit (that makes sense), but I might be reading quite a bit, so it seems this newly allocated input buffer could get pretty large. I don't want that to happen...

Is there a better way to be going about this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a RandomAccessFile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably are looking for the [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

Another option

If you are using Java 7  it includes a new ByteChannel, [`SeekableByteChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html). This Channel maintains a current position, so you can read and write from this position. That allows random access positions.

> SeekableByteChannel - A **SeekableByteChannel** extends ByteChannel and
>   allows to maintain and modify the current position on the underlying
>   entity to which it is connected. It has methods to get the size of the
>   underlying entity or truncate it to a given size, if permitted.

Answer (score 0):

RandomAccessFile.seek(long position) and FileChannel.position(long position) can set the file position from which they read / write data.